# loosing context in statics method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What i doing wrong?
I have a Schema

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PolicySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  number: { type: 'String', required: true },
  startDate: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date, required: true },
  endDate: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date, required: true },
 ],
});

PolicySchema.statics.lookup = function() {
  console.log(this);
};

export {PolicySchema};
```

And when in my service i call this

```
@Injectable()
export class PolicyService {
  async test() {
    this.policyModel.schema.statics.lookup();
  }

    constructor(@InjectModel('Policy') private readonly policyModel: Model<Policy>) { }
}
```

On console i can read my 'This' context is only a { lookup: [function] }
where is my mistake? 
On 'This' i want to get function like aggregate or get schema.

Maybe i called it wrong?
Please help me :)

PS.
I use a nest.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

And it looks like you can call a `static` function directly on the model, although you will probably have to create an interface for your model that includes the new function.

So, your example above should read

```js
interface PolicyModel extends Model<Policy> {
  lookup: () => void;
}


@Injectable()
export class PolicyService {
  async test() {
    this.policyModel.lookup();
  }

  constructor(@InjectModel('Policy') private readonly policyModel: PolicyModel) { }
}
```

Comment: When i do this i get error "Property 'lookup' does not exist on type 'Model<Policy, {}>'."

Comment: I updated the example above to include a Typescript interface for the model that includes the function. That should take care of that issue. (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mongoose#static-methods)

Comment: After that its work https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mongoose#static-methods  Thank You